# NetDecoder using InverseShortTimeFourier, InverseSpectrogram, or Audio, etc., Possible?

Tags: neural-networks, sound

I'm finding it impossible to create a NetDecoder to function as the inverse equivalent of, e.g., `NetEncoder["AudioSTFT"]`, `NetEncoder["AudioSpectrogram"]`, etc.

The [documentation states](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NetDecoder.html):

> `NetDecoder[NetEncoder[[...]]]` will
>   create a decoder based on the parameters of an existing encoder.

But every variation of this formula I've tried has resulted only in **$Failed**

I've also tried to come up with a solution using the "Function" named decoder option, e.g.,
 `NetDecoder[{"Function", InverseSpectrogram[#] &}]`, but whether it's because functions like `ShortTimeFourier[]` and `InverseShortTimeFourier[]` involve "data objects" incompatible with their NetEncoder equivalents or some other misunderstanding of mine about how the named "Function" decoder is supposed to work, I just can't seem to figure out how to create NetDecoders that do what I need.

If someone could help me out here, or point me toward any resources/examples where Mathematica/WLNet and its various Audio encoders are used to create something besides a classifier, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include examples of the exact complete syntax you have tried so far.

Comment: Sorry, I supposed "every variation" covered it, but, for example: `NetDecoder[NetEncoder["AudioSTFT"]]`, `enc = NetEncoder["AudioSTFT"]; NetDecoder[enc]`, `dec = NetDecoder[{"Function", InverseSpectrogram[#] &}]`,  `dec = NetDecoder[{"Function", InverseShortTimeFourier[#] &}]` (when fed `enc=NetEncoder["AudioSTFT"] yields **Expecting a ShortTimeFourierData object or a numeric matrix instead of Numeric Array**, etc.

Comment: In Mathematica 13.2, `NetDecoder["Audio"]`, `NetDecoder["AudioSTFT"]`, etc, still fail. :(